# Round number UP to multiple of 10

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

How do I round number UP to the multiple of 10 in PostgreSQL easily?

Example:

```
In      Out
100 --> 100
111 --> 120
123 --> 130
```

Sample data:

```
create table sample(mynumber numeric);

insert into sample values (100);
insert into sample values (111);
insert into sample values (123);
```

I can use:

```
select 
 mynumber,
 case
    when mynumber = round(mynumber,-1) then mynumber 
    else round(mynumber,-1) + 10 end as result
from
 sample;
```

This works well, but looks ugly. Is there simpler way of doing this?

You can find SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/2d032/1)

Comment: (number + 9)/10 could be applied directly to all cases to get a round up to multiple of 10. not sure how to in postgresql.

Comment: Can the numbers be negative? It yes, specify rounding "up". Can there be fractional digits?

Comment: In my case I do have only positive numbers. There are fractional digits.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
select ceil(a::numeric / 10) * 10
from (values (100), (111), (123)) s(a);
 ?column? 
----------
      100
      120
      130
```

Comment: Nice.  I use a divisor with a decimal point instead of an explicit cast to numeric, e.g. `ceil(a / 10.0) * 10`.